# Cookies timer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I created a cookie timer, and I am so new with cookie, plus i am not a pro with jquery so i created the below function.

1st it clears a particular box on click, but doesn't show up when i alter the cookie time, i don't know where the issue would certainly be from.

below is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#close-even-more').click(function () {
    $('.even-more-sq-rt').hide();

    function display() { 
      var now = new Date();
      var time = now.getTime();
      var expireTime = time + 1000*30;
      now.setTime(expireTime);
      var tempExp = 'fri, 08 Dec 2017 05:03:17 GMT';
      document.cookie = 'cookie=ok;expires='+now.toGMTString()+';path=/';
      console.log(document.cookie);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Side question.  Why are you declaring display() in the click handler?

Comment: I'm also not sure of where you are drawing an association between hiding the element on the screen and the time you are putting on a cookie.  But as far as I can tell `display()` is not called in your snippet.

Comment: @taplar **thanks bro**... like i said i am no pro in jquery and would learn to call, how do i call this :-)

Comment: It's a function.  You call it like any other function.  But you should move it outside the click handler.  There isn't a reason to keep declaring it over and over for each click.

Comment: cool one last thing how does the timing works .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies  , https://superuser.com/questions/356265/what-do-browsers-do-with-expired-cookies